# Nested list in python doesn't behave as expected

Tags: python, nested

in python let's write

```py
a=[[0]*2]*2
a[0][0] = 55
print(a)
```

I would expected the following output:
`[[55, 0], [0,0]]`

Comment: I have edited your code using backticks `\``, to make it more readable :) Can I just check that it's copied correctly?

Comment: This question was closed since it has already been answered elsewhere, but a recommendation to new users is that you will get more assistance if you can provide at a minimum; what you want to achieve, what happens instead and what you have tried.